# if else condition not working with array values in php

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

i have come to this strange issue.

i am getting values from array and trying to compare it but its not working.

Code-1

```
<?php
echo $data->item[0]['promocode'].'<br>';
echo $data->item[1]['promocode']; 
?>
```

Output-1

```
inhouse
inhouse
```

---

Now lets try with if else condition if both values are same or not
Code-2

```
<?php
if(($data->item[0]['promocode']) == ($data->item[1]['promocode'])){
echo "both values are same";
} else {
echo "both values are NOT same";
}?>
```

Output-2

```
both values are NOT same
```

**Very strange**

### i dont get it what i am doing wrong.

lets try above exaple with specifying variables
Code-3

```
<?php
$data0=$data->item[0]['promocode'];
$data1=$data->item[1]['promocode'];
if($data0 == $data1){
echo "both values are same";
} else {
echo "both values are NOT same";
}?>
```

Output-3

```
both values are NOT same
```

I am pulling my hairs now.

---

Now hard coding values in variables

Code-4

```
<?
$data0='inhouse';
$data1='inhouse';
if($data0 == $data1){
echo "both values are same";
} else {
echo "both values are NOT same";
}?>
```

Output-4

```
both values are same
```

---

So my question is why is this happening ?

i have array of elements and i wanna check previous value with the current value if try then do something.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint: What is the result of `if (strlen($data0=$data->item[0]['promocode']) == strlen($data0=$data->item[1]['promocode']))`

Comment: Try `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Isn't `===` even stronger and with more restrictions than `==`, so when `==` gives false, `===` will surely give false, too? Just asking to see whether I understood them correctly.

Comment: There indeed seems to be a trailing whitespace as seen here http://i49.tinypic.com/1ffmrr.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming both entries are strings (as shown in your first code example) my guess would be that your entries have unequal leading and / or trailing whitespace. Try normalising them first, eg

```
if (trim($data->item[0]['promocode']) == trim($data->item[1]['promocode']))
```

To see what's going on, try modifying your first example to

```
<?php
    printf('<pre>"%s"%s"%s"</pre>',
        $data->item[0]['promocode'],
        PHP_EOL,
        $data->item[1]['promocode']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php
   if(($data->item[0]['promocode']) === ($data->item[1]['promocode'])){
     echo "both values are same";
   } else {
     echo "both values are NOT same";
   }
?>
```

or you can use

```
strcmp($data->item[0]['promocode'],$data->item[1]['promocode']);
```

Comment: The *identical* operator is only going to make the comparison more likely to fail. `strcmp()` is not going to yield any different result than `==`

Comment: I think strcmp is more specified for string functioning right..??your trimming may delete spaces and may others but the questioner asked for comparission...

Comment: No, [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) will give you the *difference* between two strings as a number (0 for equal). Using it to determine equality is no different than `$a == $b`

Comment: Yah then you can use if(strcmp(str1,str2) == 0) then they are equal otherwise not....even it determine the 'cases' also

Comment: As pointed out already, `strcmp($str1, $str2) == 0` is not going to yield a different result than `$str1 == $str2`

Answer (score 0):

I use strlen($var) also for debugging...

```
<?php
if( strlen($data->item[0]['promocode']) == strlen($data->item[1]['promocode']) ){
  if(($data->item[0]['promocode']) == ($data->item[1]['promocode'])){
    echo "both values are same";
  }
  else {
    echo "both values are NOT same";
  }
}
else{
 echo 'ther are different because 
 strlen($data->item[0]["promocode"]='.strlen($data->item[0]['promocode']).' and 
 strlen($data->item[1][|promocode"]) = '. strlen($data->item[1]['promocode']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the non-type-casted conditional statement === to see if they are the same type.
Or for debugging perposes display the variable type to make sure you don't accidentally have some NULL objects or other weird data types.

```
if($data0 !== $data1) echo gettype($data0).' !== '.gettype($data1);
```

That should help you find out what you're actually comparing. Another option is to use `var_dump($data);` to actually display the variables all together. See if theres some discrepancies in the data types. It should help you find out if your object is actually populating correctly.